# Microsoft Word clears clipboard data when it closes

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, clipboard

When I copy information from a document (just some text) out of Microsoft Word, then close the document and re-open it, the clipboard data is gone.

What is happening here, and how can I stop Microsoft Word from messing with my clipboard data?

---

**Steps to Reproduce:**

- With an existing Word document, mark it as Read-only on Windows.
- Open Word.
- Make a modification. Copy some text.
- Attempt to save. The "Save As..." dialog appears because the file is read-only.
- Do not save. Press Cancel instead.
- Close Word.
- Mark the file as not Read-only.
- Open the document again.
- Try to paste.

When you try to paste, nothing happens, the clipboard was cleared.

Comment: What version of Word and Windows are you using?

Comment: Windows 7 Pro 32-bit, Office 2010.

Answer (score 1):

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/copy-and-paste-multiple-items-by-using-the-office-clipboard-HA010163602.aspx

Per Microsoft,the clipboard data is not cleared. I know you do get a prompt if you have large amounts of data in the clipboard, but I do not know of a way to automatically clear the clipboard on exit.

My guess is this is a third party program.

Or perhaps you can provide a specific example.

Comment: I added reproduction steps. The Read-only property is because I'm dealing with documents coming from SharePoint, which are sometimes marked as Read-only.

Comment: Odd, mine worked just fine. . . but I was using a local document.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft didn't think this through. Years ago, we could copy a spreadsheet cell, save the file, and then paste the data elsewhere. Now if we do this, the data disappears! The only answer I can come up with is to copy the data, paste it where it needs to be pasted, remember to go back to the original program and save or close it, then go back to the program where the data was pasted and continue.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1106676)